# How to process failed Futures

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I'm integrating with a legacy library that I have no control of.

It has the following interface defined:

```
interface Factory {
    Future<Void> subscribe(Context c);
}
```

This "subscribe" method is called frequently and by different threads. The only situation when I care about the result of "Future.get()" is when it fails, so I can get and process the exception. This doesn't have to happen in calling thread. Plus, blocking calling thread on "Future.get()" can be quite expensive in my case, cause it may take seconds to fullfill even if successfull.

So my task is to somehow "post process" all these futures, filtering failed ones. Basically, I can see two possible approaches:

Approach #1:

On obtaining an instance of Future, submit a separate Runnable to external executor that will do the required:

```
    executor.submit(
        new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    future.get();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    // process the exception
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

The drawback of this approach is that we are still blocking a thread for potentially long time period. And as I said, this code snippet will be executed rather frequently.

Approach #2:

On obtaining an instance of Future, place it to some collection and dedicate a separate single thread that will periodically run through elements of this collection doing the processing:

```
    while(true){
        Iterator<Future<Void>> iterator = collection.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Future<Void> future = iterator.next();
            if(future.isDone()){
                try {
                    future.get();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    // process the exception
                } finally {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000); // sleep
    }
```

What do you think? Is there a better way of solving the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no hands on the creation of the `Future` the best option is not available, trigger the processing from the `Future` itself by using a customized `Future`.

So in your case I recommend a pattern that might look like a mixture of your two options. Add the `Future`s to a (thread-safe) queue and submit `Runnable`s to an executor which process all items in a loop. So you can limit the number of threads by configuring the `Executor`, i.e. don’t have as much threads as `Future`s but still can have more than one and don’t have to keep these post-processing threads alive all the time.

In order to avoid an infinite loop when re-queue unfinished items, use a local collection to separate pending from re-queued items:

```
static BlockingQueue<Future<?>> PENDING = …;
static int MAX_ITEMS_PER_JOB = …;
…
/*scheduling code …*/new Runnable() {
  public void run()
  {
    ArrayList<Future<?>> myLocalItems=new ArrayList<>();
    PENDING.drainTo(myLocalItems, MAX_ITEMS_PER_JOB);
    for(Future<?> f:myLocalItems) {
      if(!f.isDone()) PENDING.offer(f); // re-queue
      try {
        f.get();
      } catch(ExecutionException ex) {
        handleException(ex.getCause());
      }
    }
  }
};
```

So this `Runnable` will check and process a limited number of `Future`s and return then so it’s suitable to be submitted multiple times to do parallel processing if a lot of items are pending but do no harm if a lesser number is pending as the jobs will not hang around if there’s nothing to do. They are even suitable for `scheduleWithFixedDelay` using a `ScheduledExecutorService`.